# wampserver 404 error The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: wampserver

I installed `wamp server` and it works fine as the icon color is green and even the localhost works fine, but the problem happens when I add any PHP file inside `www folder` and try to access the file it gives me this message:

```
404 error The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you please put url here?

Comment: Please check your localhost working fine.

Comment: @Gufran Hasan I mean I can access the localhst:8080 without any issue

Comment: @Kamlesh Solanki  http://localhost:8080/test.php

Comment: Pass your folder name as http://localhost:8080/project_name or file_name

Comment: @Gufran Hasan I tried but I get the same error

Comment: Please check your file extension should test.php not test.php.txt

Comment: @anatermj use like this http://localhost/test.php

Comment: @Kamlesh Solanki I cant because I am using port 8080

Comment: can you please share screenshot for the wamp folder with created PHP file

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/o29bQKg.png

Comment: Please dont put your code in the `\wamp\www` folder. Make a sub folder like `wamp\www\project1` and put you code in there. The `www` folder is only for wampservers own code

Comment: It is also a better idea to work out why port 80 was not working. Probably if you are using Windows 10 is because IIS gets installed automatically. If you are not using IIS then uninstall it completely

Answer (score 0):

How to run PHP project or files on wamp server at localhost?

1. Run wamp server
2. Create PHP project or file inside `C://wamp/www/` directory.
3. Run your project or file means open URL in Browser ex: `http://localhost/file_name.php or folder name`

If a folder has an `index.php` file it will run by calling folder name in URL.

Comment: @anater, Please do one thing enabled AllowOverride directive in apache\conf\httpd.conf

Comment: Gufran That page on the wampserver forum is for a Very very old version of WAMPServer

Answer (score 0):

Running your project or file; means opening the URL in a browser

**Example**:

http://localhost/file_name.php or folder name

Answer (score 0):

You should check the **httpd-vhosts.conf** file  via **/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.41/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf.** the follwings; the port numbers here for example 83 cause it was my choice:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:83>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#
<VirtualHost *:83>
    ServerName myProject
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp64/www/spip-projet-v"
    <Directory  "d:/wamp64/www/spip-projet-v/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```